# Suma factorial en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursión

Estoy tratando de crear una función que tome dos parámetros (a, b) y los sume recursivamente, desde a hasta b incluyendo b, devolviendo el resultado de la suma. De esta manera (1, 4) devuelve 10 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4).

En mi diseño algorítmico la función de abajo debería funcionar pero no lo hace:

```
var sumAll = function(a, b) {

  let sum = a;    

  for (let index = a; index <= b; index++) {   
      sum += index;        
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumAll(1, 4)); // devuelve 11
```

¿Que le falta a la lógica de mi programa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas sumando `a` dos veces.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
var sumAll = function(a, b) {

  let sum = 0;    

  for (let index = a; index <= b; index++) {   
      sum += index;        
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Es correcto, esa es la solución, sin embargo no comprendo porque, ya que la suma debe empezar en el numero que el usuario indique, ¿no se  supone que sum debería entoces ser igual al primer parámetro?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo asi, pero en ese caso tu for loop no tendria que empezar en a, sino que en a + 1, porque sino estarias sumando a dos veces.